# Change color of the dots

Tags: jquery, html, css, owl-carousel

I want to change the default color background of the dots on inactive or active state. I use **Owl Carousel Slider**

Here's the dots I want to change the color of the dots.
[image]

I tried the css below but it is not working

```
.owl-pagination .owl-page{
     background-color: white;

}
.owl-pagination .owl-page .active
{
    background-color: aqua;
}
```

Comment: You need to add the <span> ex:  .owl-pagination .owl-page span{background: blue;}

Comment: I tried it but it's not working.

Answer (score 4):

Solution to change the color for **all dots**:

```
.owl-carousel span {
    width:10px;
    height:10px;
    margin:5px 7px;
    background: blue !important;
    display:block;
    -webkit-backface-visibility:visible;
    -webkit-transition:opacity 200ms ease;
    -moz-transition:opacity 200ms ease;
    -ms-transition:opacity 200ms ease;
    -o-transition:opacity 200ms ease;
    transition:opacity 200ms ease;
    -webkit-border-radius:30px;
    -moz-border-radius:30px;
    border-radius:30px;
}
```

Solution to change the color of an **active dot**:

```
.owl-carousel .active span {
    width:10px;
    height:10px;
    margin:5px 7px;
    background: red !important;
    display:block;
    -webkit-backface-visibility:visible;
    -webkit-transition:opacity 200ms ease;
    -moz-transition:opacity 200ms ease;
    -ms-transition:opacity 200ms ease;
    -o-transition:opacity 200ms ease;
    transition:opacity 200ms ease;
    -webkit-border-radius:30px;
    -moz-border-radius:30px;
    border-radius:30px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is for Owl Carousel:

```css
.owl-theme .owl-dots .owl-dot span{
    width:10px;
    height:10px;
    margin:5px 7px;
    background: #b71616 !important;
    display:block;
    -webkit-backface-visibility:visible;
    -webkit-transition:opacity 200ms ease;
    -moz-transition:opacity 200ms ease;
    -ms-transition:opacity 200ms ease;
    -o-transition:opacity 200ms ease;
    transition:opacity 200ms ease;
    -webkit-border-radius:30px;
    -moz-border-radius:30px;
    border-radius:30px;
}
```

This is Bootstrap Carousel:

```css
.carousel-indicators li{
    display:inline-block;
    width:10px;
    height:10px;
    margin:1px;
    text-indent:-999px;
    cursor:pointer;
    background-color: #ff0000 !important;
    border:1px solid #fff;
    border-radius:10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
.owl-pagination .owl-page span {
    background-color: white;
}
.owl-pagination .owl-page .active span
{
    background-color: aqua;
}
```

Comment: You should do more than provide code in an answer. You should explain what the OP did wrong and how your code resolves that issue.

Answer (score 0):

OWL Carousel, If you want to get rid of dot colors for active and hover state:

```
.owl-theme .owl-dots .owl-dot {
    -----
    background-color: transparent;
    &.active, &:hover {
        color: $primary-color(your color);

        span {
            background: transparent; 
        }
      }

    span {
        font-size: 2.5rem;
        font-family: $primary-font (your font);
        background: transparent;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Hi try this it works**

```
.owl-theme .owl-dots .owl-dot.active span, .owl-theme .owl-dots .owl-dot:hover span {
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#fe6e00, #eb9859);
}

.owl-theme .owl-nav [class*=owl-]:hover {
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#fe6e00, #eb9859);
    color: #FFF;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

For Angular Project, need to add '::ng-deep' to change dot color.
If you need to change dot color for only one page, remove '!important'.

```
  ::ng-deep .owl-theme .owl-dots .owl-dot span {
    background: #D6D6D6 !important; /* dots color */
  }
 
 ::ng-deep .owl-theme .owl-dots .owl-dot.active span,
  .owl-theme .owl-dots .owl-dot:hover span {
    background: #FF0000 !important; /*active and on hover color*/
  }
```